# Remote Powershell to retrieve specific registry value from lots of servers

Tags: powershell, remote-registry

I have the following..

```
$output = @()
$servers =Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\List3.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    trap [Exception] {continue}
    Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry
    $key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'Microsoft Antimalware'\'Signature Updates'"

    $regkey=Get-RegBinary -ComputerName $server -Key $Key -Value SignatuesLastUpdated

    #$regkey=(Get-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'Microsoft Antimalware'\'Signature Updates').getValue('SignaturesLastUpdated')

    #$regkey=[datetime]::ParseExact("01/02/03", "dd/MM/yy", $null) | Export-csv -path c:\temp\avinfo.csv -append

    #$regkey
}

$output | Select $server , $Regkey | Export-Csv c:\temp\avinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I think it's pretty close but doesn't work as needed - can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here - been reading a lot and managed to get this far, just need the help to finalise.

Thanks

Comment: ^Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: `SignatuesLastUpdated` should be `SignaturesLastUpdated`

Comment: You say *doesn't work as needed*... What exactly doesn't work and how is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... so there is *alot* that needed to be changed to get this to work. I will update the answer frequently after this is posted.

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\List3.txt"
$key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Signature Updates"

$servers | ForEach-Object{
    $server = $_
    Try{
        Get-RegBinary -ComputerName $server -Key $Key -Value SignatuesLastUpdated -ErrorAction Stop
    } Catch [exception]{
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ComputerName = $server
            Data = "Unable to retrieve data"
        }
    }
} | Select ComputerName,@{Label=$value;Expression={If(!($_.Data -is [string])){[System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes($_.data)}Else{$_.Data}}} | Export-Csv c:\temp\avinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What the above code will do is more in line with your intentions. Take the list and for each item get the key data from that server. If there is an issue getting that data then we output a custom object stating that so we can tell in the output if there was an issue. The part that is up in the air is how you want to export the binary data to file. As it stands it should create a space delimited string of the bytes.

The issues that you did have that should be highlighted are

1. No need to import the module for *every* server. Moved that call out of the loop
2. You have declared the variable `$output` but do not populate it during your loop process. This is important for the `foreach` construct. You were, in the end, sending and empty array to you csv. My answer does not need it as it just uses standard output.
3. As [@Meatspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392644/meatspace) pointed out you had a typo here: `SignatuesLastUpdated`
4. `Get-RegBinary` does not by default create terminating errors which are needed by try/catch blocks. Added `-ErrorAction Stop`. Don't think your code `trap [Exception] {continue}` would have caught anything.
5. The single quotes you have in your `$key` might have prevented the path from being parsed. You were trying to escape spaces and just need to enclose the whole string in a set of quotes to achieve that.
6. While `Select` can use variables they are there, in a basic form, to select property names. In short what you had was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that - tried the script as per your comment (after correcting the typo I had originally made) - well it ran and almost every result was "Unable to retrieve data"...A few however gave "System.Byte{}" which I am guessing is a positive result but doesn't provide the actual data.

Comment: I am supposing that the remote registry service is down for most of the servers I am looking at, so moving on to the next method.

Comment: @DominicLambert FYI I update the answer to output a string representation of the data